# Passing in values into a jquery function with a # at the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `script` which is located in its own `.js file`, which I believe is used to look for a specific `anchor` and assign an onclick event where it will forward the user to another page.

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        "use strict";
        $(".popup a").on(
            'click',
            function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#the_link").click();
            }
        );
    }
);
```

What does `#the_link` mean in the context of the rest of the code? I am trying to find out how and where it is getting its value from but I can't find it anywhere. Help!

I also replaced `#the_link` with `www.google.com`, but then after nothing happened where before a window pops up. What could I do to make it go to google? <-- testing purposes.

PS. I am very very new to `javascript`.

PSS. In honesty, I am not sure what is going on in that code above.

Comment: It is a jQuery Selector, more specifically it is an "ID Selector".  See : http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: You really should read a jQuery tutorial first: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("#the_link") is jquery syntax, and it refers to the element with an id of "the_link" that is located in the HTML markup.

Somewhere in the HTML, you have (for example):

```
<a id="the_link" href="#">...</a>
```

Here, the href attribute is where you would insert the http://google.com to go to that link when the anchor  element is clicked.

```
<a id="the_link" href="http://google.com">...</a>
```

Alternatively you can write in your javascript:

```
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
 }
```

Comment: I have searched the solution for the_link, but nothing can be found. Any suggestions? Perhaps the code above #the_link has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

That is jquery, not plain javascript (so you might add the jquery tag to your question).

$() is jquery, and the # means *get me the element with the id of "the_link"*. Go search your document for an id="the_link", there will be no # in the id field, the # is used to tell jquery you are querying by element id, as opposed to some other type of query (by other attribute, by class, etc).

In a valid HTML document, exactly one element may have a given id, so selecting by # is a way to refer to a unique element in the document.

Comment: *"and the # means an element"* is a strange explanation for a selector.

Comment: He didn't post an answer - what are you going to upvote?

Comment: I tried to find the the_link but it didn't come up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are accessing element with id `the_link`. Some of your elements in html has attribute `id="the_link"`.

If you want to go to `google.com` when `the_link` is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("the_link").onclick = function(){
     window.location.href="http://google.com" //this goes to google.com
};
```

Comment: With jquery you can't assign an event callback using `$("#the_link").onClick = function(){ ... }`

Comment: I did a search on the_link and id="the_link" but there is no match. Any suggestions? And how does the code you mentioned fit in my code?